# Center Formula in self created environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

I use a environment called `loesung` which I created by myself. Now I have a formula in that environment, but I want to have that formulas centered. Not left aligned, here is my code:

```
%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69043/center-formula-in-self-created-environment
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{geometry}
%\geometry{left=4cm,right=3cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}[2011/02/05]

\definecolor{cloesung}{rgb}{0.972,0.93725,0.85098}

\newtheoremstyle{mystyle2}
  {\topsep}{\topsep}{}{}%
  {\bfseries}{}{.5em}{}%

\newmdtheoremenv[hidealllines=true,
backgroundcolor=cloesung,skipabove=\topsep,
skipbelow=\topsep]{loesung}{L\"osung}

\begin{document}

\begin{loesung}\text{blafasel}\\
\begin{align*}
c &= a+b\\
\intertext{description} a+b \intertext{is ....}
d &= h+g
\end{align*}
\end{loesung}

\end{document}
```

So my problem is, that the formulas should be centered? How can I do this? I tried `\centering` and `\begin{center}` but it does not work?

Thanks a lot
cya

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Your code gives `Undefined control sequence. l.64 newmdtheoremenv`. Also it has to be `$a+b$` instead of `&a+b&`. Usually equations should be centered by default and only left aligned if `amsmath` gets the option `fleqn`.

Comment: well thanks a lot for your help, but my example is what I have? I implemented the mdframed package, so newmdtheoremenv should not be an undefinde control sequence?

And I did not use the option fleqn on amsmath......

Comment: In your MWE, there are two displayed equations, each nicely centered, and one inline expression (part of the `\intertext` command) that won't compile correctly as currently written because you've written `&a+b&` rather than `$a+b$`. Or is it the case that you're trying to center the `a+b` part on a line by itself? In that case, you should write `\[a+b\] (and break up the material in `\intertext` accordingly. Incidentally, I do *not* get an error message about `newmdtheoremenv` being undefined.

Comment: ? What, but my latex does not center it?! I want the a+b centered, so it stands on the middle, but on my pdf it is on the left, as the normal text!

Comment: In that case, don't use the `\intertext` command, which is there to place (usually) short pieces of text in between consecutive displayed equations.

Comment: but what else ?

Comment: You can just use `\text`. Also a MWE should be boiled down to what is necessary. The error btw. is probably because my version of mdframed is too old.

Comment: no! \text is not working, because then the formula is written on the right margin and it is not readable anymore

Comment: Did you look at the two solutions below?

Comment: Independent from the actual problem it can cause problems to call two packages with nearly same functions. Check your packages you call: why `xcolor` two times and `color`? For a good MWE there is no need for packages like `bookmark`, `xcolor` and so on.

Comment: Since you are using `\listfiles`, process the *exact* example code you posted in your question, and then upload elsewhere the obtained `.log` file; add a comment here providing the link to the `.log` file so we can have a look at it.

Comment: @StochastiprocStu The `a+b` *is* centered, but since it is part of an `align` it's placed in the first (right flush) column of this alignment. The *whole* alignment is centered.

Comment: @StochastiprocStu Make sure your are not using the `[fleqn]` option in your documentclass, that will move all equations to the left.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem has nothing to do with your self-created environment.  Witness

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\hrule
\begin{align*}
  c &= a+b\\
  \intertext{description} 
  a+b 
  \intertext{is \dots}
  d &= h+g
\end{align*}
\hrule
\end{document}
```

[image: Unaligned output]

So what you are really asking is how to do you center one equation in the middle of an alignment.  That can be acheived by putting the extra equation inside the `\intertext` command in its own maths environment as follows:

```
\begin{align*}
  c &= a+b\\
  \intertext{description \begin{equation*} a+b \end{equation*} is \dots}
  d &= h+g
\end{align*}
```

[image: Centered output]

Put into your sample environment this looks like:

[image: Sample output]

However, I would generally avoid such widely separated alignments and write your example simply as

```
\begin{loesung}
  blafasel
  \begin{equation*}
c = a+b
\end{equation*}
description
\begin{equation*}
  a+b
\end{equation*}
is \dots
\begin{equation*}
d = h+g
\end{equation*}
\end{loesung}
```

[image: Simpler output]

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you want is possibly this:

```
\begin{loesung}
\text{ }\\
\begin{align*}
c&=a+b\\
\intertext{description}
a+b\\ 
\intertext{is \dots}
d&=h+g
\end{align*}
\end{loesung}
```

[image]

Comment: no? I just want the c=a+b and the d=h+g in the middle of the page, not on the left side. And my problem is, that now it is on the left side and not in the middle.....

Comment: @HStudUFD -- The code above already centers both `c=a+b` and `d=h+g` on their respective lines. I've added an image file the output that results from the (modified) MWE.

Comment: yeah ! the picture is right! but on my pdf the formula is on the left side as the words description and is...?

Comment: The image above is generated with the code shown, *and absolutely nothing else*. If your TeX distribution doesn't generate this output as well, then there must be something wrong with your TeX distribution's setup or implementation. Please indicate which TeX distribution you use: TeXLive (2012? 2011?), MikTeX (2.9?, 2.8?), or something else? When was the last time you updated the LaTeX packages you load in the (not so minimal!) code example you provide?

Comment: ok I am working on getting a better minimal code,
I uploaded the packages just a few days ago, 5 days perhaps, I use Miktex 2.9 and viewing and editing it with TexWorks 0.4.4 r1003